# Function Definition and Call in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

When you call a function you must define it first, otherwise you will get an error 
message. But when you call a functions by another function it's okay to define a fuction after that, for example:

```
def repeat_name():
    print_name()
    print_name()

def print_name():
    print('Mahmud')

repeat_name()
```

In this example we call print_name function in repeat_name function before its defination, and it works fine, but why does this happen?

Note: I'm a beginner in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it being interpreted as it is run, so the items inside the `repeat_name` function are not checked until the first time it is called at `repeat_name()` after the `print_name` function.

If you put the call to `repeat_name()` above the `print_name` function it would also fail.

That is why if you have the code:

```
def my_func(x):
    print(x)

my_func("hello world")
```

It doesn't freak out that it doesn't know what `x` is, becasue `x` will be defined when you first call that function `my_func("hello world")`

Comment: Thank you! I understand now. Functions' definitions have no effect on the execution, so when I call repeat_name function I actually call print_name function twice, is that right?